# Issue downloading Xcode provisioning profile

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

`Xcode` - > `Preference` - > `provisioning profiles` -> Download not enabled

My screen looks like below screen shot. (download button is disabled).

[image]

While enabling the push notification in Xcode, it shows couldn't load provisioning profile from data.

The displayed error looks like below.

[image]

Comment: are you using Xcode managed provisioning profile or manual one??

Comment: that was manual one i think , bcoz i want to link firebase push notification to xcode

Comment: Have you try to click on fix issue button for fixing issue automatically ?

Comment: Yup, But fix not worked for me

Comment: Just OFF and then On the switch button it will automatically update the entitlement with push notification enabled.Keep your internet ON please. again check the certification enable APNS and generate certificate and install.